# Having multiple folders be "desktop" folders

Tags: directory, windows-10, desktop

I have two disk drives on my PC (one SSD and one HDD) and basically what I want to do is to have files from both of these drives in my desktop.

Currently my desktop folder is in the SSD and I want to have direct access from the desktop to some of my files in the HDD. One solution may be to just create a link in the SSD folder to the HDD folder, but I should do this for every folder/file I want on the dekstop.

So, is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to create another desktop folder on the HDD (or some analogous action that brings the same result)? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do, can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple Desktop folders, you can have just one Desktop folder at once, but you can move the whole Desktop folder to another location or drive. Just right-click the Desktop folder inside your "User folder" (eg: your name/nickname probably) and select "Properties", then in the "Location" tab "Find Target..." (choose the new location/path) and click on "Move..." button. All your Desktop files will be moved there (the entire folder actually).
Bye.